# Hamiltonian spectrum with degeneracies equal to powers of 2?

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, representation-theory

Does there exist a (finite or continuous) group such that every irreducible representation has dimension equal to a power of 2?

The context is that I have a quantum many-body Hamiltonian on a 1D spin 1/2 lattice of arbitrary size, whose spectrum has degeneracies that are only powers of 2. Furthermore, larger and larger degeneracies appear as the lattice size is increased.

A possible source of degeneracies is that the Hamiltonian has a symmetry described by a group with the aforementioned property. Is there any such physical symmetry?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Sure. I've copied it to Math. But I had a physicsy motivation, see edited question. Perhaps some one might have encountered such a Hamiltonian?

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4408377/11127